# Unity, how to pass null via ParameterOverride?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to pass `null` to one of resolved class constructor parameters. However, `ParameterOverride` does not accept null as value (from implementation it seems like `null` internally is interpreted as "not resolved").

I also tried with providing parameter with default value or overloaded constructor without this parameter - but in such cases Unity always complains, that I did not provided value for this parameter.

Example code:

```
unityContainer.Resolve<MyClass>(new ParameterOverride(myField, null));
```

Comment: Is there any error message? What is the type of your field?

Comment: `ParameterOverride` disallows passing null through second parameter (`ArgumentNullException`). Type is an interface (`ISomething`). If I omit the parameter, Unity complains about unresolved parameter in either of described cases.

Comment: Then it means you should create a “null” object of type of your field and pass it

Answer (score 1):

There are some approaches you could use to inject a null dependency (e.g. `InjectionFactory` that injects a null) but I didn't see a way with a `ParameterOverride`.  There might be an easy way to do this but I didn't think of it right away.

However, one way to inject null using a `ParameterOverride` would be to create an `InjectionParameterValue` that specifically injects null.  This would bypass Unity's null checks. It could look something like this:

```
public class NullInjectionParameterValue : InjectionParameterValue
{
    public NullInjectionParameterValue(Type parameterType)
    {
        this.ParameterTypeName = parameterType.GetTypeInfo().Name;
    }

    public override bool MatchesType(Type t)
    {
        return !t.IsValueType || (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null);
    }

    public override IResolverPolicy GetResolverPolicy(Type typeToBuild)
    {
        return new LiteralValueDependencyResolverPolicy(null);
    }

    public override string ParameterTypeName { get; }
}

public class NullInjectionParameterValue<TParameter> 
    : NullInjectionParameterValue where TParameter : class
{
    public NullInjectionParameterValue()
        : base(typeof(TParameter))
    {
    }
}
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
container.Resolve<MyClass>(
    new ParameterOverride("myField", new NullInjectionParameterValue<string>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of behavior isn't unique to Unity - most DI containers do not allow you to inject `null` (unless you manually intervene or extend the container to allow it).

From [Microsoft's Unity 2.1 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882(v=pandp.20).aspx) (since Unity 5 has no documentation results in Google):

> You cannot supply `null` as the value to inject. You must explicitly provide an InjectionParameter, as with types.

When injecting services it is not logical to make them `null`. That would mean there would need to be `null` checking code strewn all throughout the code in order to deal with this situation. Instead, we protect the member variables so they can never be `null` to make the code robust.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    // Can only be set by the constructor
    private readonly IMyClass myClass;

    public MyService(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        // Can never set to null
        if (myclass == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myClass));
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Null checking is not required here (or anywhere else in
        // this class) because we are guaranteed to have an instance
        // when this object is instantiated.
        // if (this.myClass != null)
        this.myClass.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

So what do we do when we want to represent *nothing*? Use a [Null Object Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object) to satisfy the `IMyClass` requirement using a class with *null behavior*.

```
public class NullMyClass : IMyClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // The logical "null" behavior is to do nothing here
    }
}
```

Now `NullMyClass` can be used with Unity to represent a no-op for `IMyClass`.

```
new MyService(null); // Throws NullReferenceException (desired to make the code robust)
new MyService(new MyClass()); // Implements concrete behavior
new MyService(new NullMyClass()) // Implements null behavior (no-op)

unityContainer.Resolve<IMyClass>(new ParameterOverride(myField, new NullMyClass()));
```

Reference: [How can I inject a property only if the value is non-null at runtime using Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445507/how-can-i-inject-a-property-only-if-the-value-is-non-null-at-runtime-using-unity)